# How do I get fetch result from API to store as a global variable?

Tags: javascript, scope, fetch-api

I am working on a project where I pull an API of US GDP and then create a graph from the data. Right now I'm hung up on the first part of the problem in that I am struggling to get the JSON to store in a variable so I can work with it in the rest of my project. I've looked at a few other threads and haven't gotten a solution to work for me.

Below is my current code.

```
let jsondata =;

fetch('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FreeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/GDP-data.json').then(
    function(u){ return u.json();}
  ).then(
    function(json){
        jsondata = json;
        console.log(jsondata)
    }
  )


console.log(jsondata)
```

Currently, I can console.log(json) and console.log(jsondata) within my second function. However, even though I've declared the variable outside of the function, it doesn't make the variable its self global. What am I missing?

Comment: The variable *is* global, you're just printing it before it gets assigned.

Comment: Store the promise for the json data instead in the global variable, then wait for it each time you need the data.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`fetch` is an asynchronous function. That means when the function is called, it is added to an event-loop and the code will continue. When it reaches your last line the `jsondata` variable will not yet be filled since the `fetch` function hasn't completed yet.

You should add an `await` in front of you function to make sure it is finished before the code will continue. For examples, see: https://dev.to/shoupn/javascript-fetch-api-and-using-asyncawait-47mp

```
let jsondata = "";
let apiUrl = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FreeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/GDP-data.json"

async function getJson(url) {
    let response = await fetch(url);
    let data = await response.json()
    return data;
}

async function main() {
    //OPTION 1
    getJson(apiUrl)
        .then(data => console.log(data));

    //OPTION 2
    jsondata = await getJson(apiUrl)
    console.log(jsondata);
}

main();
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried the following

let jsondata;

 fetch('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FreeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/GDP-data.json').then(
    await function(u){ return u.json();}
  ).then(
    await function(json){
        jsondata = json;
        console.log(jsondata)
    }
  )


console.log(jsondata)

However I am now getting the error message "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" That references my the line with my first await. Any thoughts?

Comment: Check my updated answer